# detect moving object with opencv and python

Tags: python, image, opencv, image-processing

i found very interesting article  about  detection of moving objects, here is correspondng link :[Detection of moving object](https://debuggercafe.com/moving-object-detection-using-frame-differencing-with-opencv/)

and also corresponding article : [Article about object detection](https://research.ijcaonline.org/volume102/number7/pxc3898647.pdf)

i followed  code  and  try to implement my self, here is corresponding code :

```
import  cv2
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from Background_Image_Creation import get_background
cap =cv2.VideoCapture("video_1.mp4")
#print(cap.get(cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_COUNT))
#print(cap.get(cv2.CAP_PROP_FPS))
frame_width = int(cap.get(3))
frame_height = int(cap.get(4))
save_name = "Result.mp4"
# define codec and create VideoWriter object
out = cv2.VideoWriter(save_name,cv2.VideoWriter_fourcc(*'mp4v'), 10, (frame_width, frame_height))
background_frame =get_background("video_1.mp4")
background = cv2.cvtColor(background_frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
print(background.shape)
frame_count =0
consecutive_frame=8
#frame_diff_list =[]
while cap.isOpened():
    ret,frame =cap.read()
    print(ret)
    print(frame.shape)
    if ret==True:
        frame_count+=1
        orig_frame =frame.copy()
        gray =cv2.cvtColor(frame,cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
        if frame_count % consecutive_frame == 0 or frame_count == 1:
            frame_diff_list =[]
        frame_diff = cv2.absdiff(gray, background)
        ret, thresh = cv2.threshold(frame_diff, 50, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY)
        dilate_frame = cv2.dilate(thresh, None, iterations=2)
        frame_diff_list.append(dilate_frame)
        print(frame_diff_list)
        if len(frame_diff_list) == consecutive_frame:
            # add all the frames in the `frame_diff_list`
            sum_frames = sum(frame_diff_list)
            print(sum_frames)
            # find the contours around the white segmented areas
            contours, hierarchy = cv2.findContours(sum_frames, cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
            # draw the contours, not strictly necessary
            for i, cnt in enumerate(contours):
                cv2.drawContours(frame, contours, i, (0, 0, 255), 3)
            for contour in contours:
                # continue through the loop if contour area is less than 500...
                # ... helps in removing noise detection
                if cv2.contourArea(contour) < 500:
                    continue
                # get the xmin, ymin, width, and height coordinates from the contours
                (x, y, w, h) = cv2.boundingRect(contour)
                # draw the bounding boxes
                cv2.rectangle(orig_frame, (x, y), (x + w, y + h), (0, 255, 0), 2)

            cv2.imshow('Detected Objects', orig_frame)
            out.write(orig_frame)
            if cv2.waitKey(100) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
                break
        else:
            break

cap.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

code  for background   frame creation is also presented :

```
import numpy as np
import cv2
import  matplotlib.pyplot as plt
def get_background(path):
    cap =cv2.VideoCapture(path)
    frame_indices =cap.get(cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_COUNT)*np.random.uniform(size=50)
    frames =[]
    for idx in frame_indices:
        cap.set(cv2.CAP_PROP_POS_FRAMES,idx)
        ret,frame =cap.read()
        frames.append(frame)
    median_frame = np.median(frames, axis=0).astype(np.uint8)
    return median_frame
#median_frame =get_background("video_1.mp4")
#cv2.imshow("Median_Background",median_frame)
#cv2.waitKey(0)
#cv2.destroyAllWindows()
#plt.show()
```

code runs fine, but  output video does not contain anything, it just  1 KGB  size, one thing what i am thinking is that  this fragment

```
frame_diff_list.append(dilate_frame)
```

is  colored with yellow color, here is  screenshot :
[image]

and also when i try to print  `print(frame_diff_list)`
it just printed one output :

[image]

i  was more surprised when  i   have  tested

```
print(ret)
print(frame.shape)
```

from the begining of the  loop and it just printed one output :

```
True
(360, 640, 3)
```

it seems that loop does not cover all  frames right? could you help  me please to figure out what is  wrong with my code?

Comment: It's the line `gray = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)`. This one just average and remove the color channel dimension. If you want the color channel back try `np.tile(cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)[..., np.newaxis], (1, 1, 3))`. But the `np.tile` is usually unnecessary as it will autocast anyway)

Comment: sorry what? this line  removes third channel exactly

Comment: Also, opencv already implement background subtraction algorithm. See https://docs.opencv.org/4.x/d1/dc5/tutorial_background_subtraction.html, You can try it out

Comment: I didn't saw that `background` is already converted to gray. What does `np.sum(frame_diff)` output (Is it `> 0`)?

Comment: i have removed this line : #if ret==True:  and it works , everything was shifted  left and  that  is . thanks for your time